# Global Hotkeys UI-control for program settings

Tags: macos, user-interface, xcode4

In my first MacOS desktop program I need to be able to put my own global hotkeys for certain actions.

In many other programs I saw a special UI-control for these purposes, like that:
[image: hotkeys UI-control]

I also want something like that in my program, but searching right library panel (and also googled), I did not found the component like this...

Where to find? How to use? The link on download and a brief tutorial would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ShortcutRecorder: http://wafflesoftware.net/shortcut/, but you want this fork: https://github.com/Kentzo/ShortcutRecorder to work with Xcode 4.

Alternatively MasShortcut: https://github.com/shpakovski/MASShortcut.

Comment: Thank you! I think that is that I certainly need!